# Can I use Improvise to pay for activated abilities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Inspiring Statuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInspiring%20Statuary%5d) states:

> Nonartifact spells you cast have improvise.

From the Comprehensive Rules (Ixalan (September 29, 2017))

> 702.125a Improvise is a static ability that functions while the spell with improvise is on the stack. “Improvise” means “For each generic
>   mana in this spell’s total cost, you may tap an untapped artifact you
>   control rather than pay that mana.”

From the Comprehensive Rules I understand that I can tap artifact to pay {1} of the spells cost. However does the same apply for activated abilities with {X} mana cost on permanents on the field. Example: [Mirage Mirror](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirage%20Mirror%5d)

> {2}: Mirage Mirror becomes a copy of target artifact, creature,
>   enchantment, or land until end of turn.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You added the definition of the ability to the question, so I don't understand what it is that you think applies to mana abilities.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thanks for calling me on this - I edited my question.

Comment: So is your question 'Can I use Improvise to pay far activated abilities?'

Comment: @diego Yes, that is my question. Will edit with the proper title now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Improvise only works for casting spells. Activating abilities, while similar is not casting a spell, thus it cannot be paid for with Improvise.

> **111.1.** A spell is a card on the stack. As the first step of being cast (see rule 601, “Casting Spells”), the card becomes a spell and is moved to the top of the stack from the zone it was in, which is usually its owner’s hand. (See rule 405, “Stack.”)
>
> **112.1b** An ability can be an activated or triggered ability on the stack. This kind of ability is an object.